# React-Native 16 Alpha 12 Migrating PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

My Expo XDE is giving me the following warning on a newly created project:

> **1:37:35 PM Warning:** checkPropTypes has been moved to a separate
>   package. Accessing React.checkPropTypes is no longer supported and
>   will be removed completely in React 16. Use the prop-types package on
>   npm instead.
>
> **1:37:35 PM Warning:** React.createClass is no longer supported. Use a
>   plain JavaScript class instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate,
>   create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in replacement.
>
> **1:37:35 PM Warning:** PropTypes has been moved to a separate package.
>   Accessing React.PropTypes is no longer supported and will be removed
>   completely in React 16. Use the prop-types package on npm instead.

[Migrating Prop-Types](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html)

Even though my code seems to be fine.. does anyone know why I still get this message or what is wrong with the following code?

**Code**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Root from './src/Root';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<View />);
  }
}

App.PropTypes = {}

export default App;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "WeDo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~20.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.47.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this: change `export default class Root extends React.Component` to `class Root extends React.Component`, and then do a simple export before your PropTypes declaration: `export default Root;`.

Comment: @Andy: Same problem, I simplified the code and still have these errors

Comment: did my solution work?

Comment: still getting: Warning: checkPropTypes has been moved to a separate package. Accessing React.checkPropTypes is no longer supported and will be removed completely in React 16. Use the prop-types packa
ge on npm instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property on `App` should be `propTypes` not `PropTypes`. You still use `PropTypes` within the object, however.

For example:

```
App.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Warning: checkPropTypes has been moved to a separate package. Accessing React.checkPropTypes is no longer supported and will be removed completely in React 16. Use the prop-types packa
ge on npm instead.

Comment: could it be something from Expo? I am using the expo client

Comment: You're importing the package so I don't know what's going on

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod#react-proptypes-to-prop-types to replace imports from React.PropTypes to 'prop-types'